# Dependency Walker Not Showing All the Depended Dll

Tags: unmanaged, fortran, dependency-walker

I have a fortran dll, and I want to know the assemblies that it depends on for [redistribution purpose](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=73161).

One thing I found out is that the dependency walker doesn't show all of the dependencies, i.e, there are some dlls that my assembly is dependent on, but dependency walker doesn't show it out.

An example would be a dll that makes use of intel mkl LAPACK dlls, but the dependency walker doesn't show that dependency.

Why this is so? And any idea how to fix this problem, or is there other more reliable tool that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dependency Walker will only show the static dependencies if you don't run it. Run it in profile, and it will show the assemblies that it dynamically loads.