# How to fully publish a Visual C# project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, package, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a Visual C# Project that is fairly basic (no more than 100 lines) but it includes some 3rd party DLL references. Running the project on the computer it was developed on has it run just fine.

In Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express, I go to `Project->Publish <project name>` and it builds some files including a setup.exe installer.

When I move those files to another computer and run the setup.exe, it correctly installs the program.

But when I run the program, it simply closes out saying:

> ProjectName.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

The command window also appears for a brief second with some errors, but it's hard to make out what it is saying. It looks something like:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for the component with CLSID { ....... } failed due to the following error: .....

I'm unable to get the command window to stay, so I cannot get the full message. But I assume this is due to the other computer not having those 3rd party DLLS.

How can I have Visual C# 2010 package *everything* including DLLs so this error does not appear? Or if that may not be the actual issue, how can I stop the command window from instantly vanishing? (I do not know the full list of DLLs required)

Or if the DLL is a registered DLL under C:\Windows\system32, is the project never going to build that into the package? Is there a way to see what it depends on?

Comment: This may help: http://dependencywalker.com/ (and apparently you might want to note this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2557954/344286)

Comment: use `Setup & Deploy Project` in VS2010 pro with all files packaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Express doesn't create fully functional installers, but only ClickOnce installers, and those also with limited functions. This kind of installer can't register COM DLLs.

What seems to be wrong in your case is that you are using a COM DLL which isn't registered on the target system. You could try to check that in your own program (like trying to create the class and catch any exceptions that are thrown by the CreateObject function), and call RegSvr32.exe /s  in order to register it. Or you just do this when the program starts the first time, before you create any object from the DLL... haven't tried that, though.

You could also make sure that you register the DLL manually on the target system before you run your program.

Moreover, when .Net uses a COM DLL, it usually creates a compatibility assembly which wraps the COM DLL and makes it accessibly to .Net. In case the DLL you use is only this compatibility assembly, you might have to locate the COM DLL it depends on manually on your system and to include it explicitly in your project's files.

In order to debug, it should be enough to put try / catch blocks around CreateObject. If that doesn't help, try adding an eventhandler for the event that is raised when an exception isn't handled by the application (this might be different according to the kind of application you create).

Comment: try/catch helped stop the cmd window from vanishing and I was able to see the error.